# JavaFX m4a (AAC) Excessive Memory Consumption. Alternatives?

Tags: javafx, memory-consumption, audioformat

I'm using javaFX in a game for playing music and sounds. Originally I was using `mp3` files for the audio, but then I learned that because of the [license](https://www.scirra.com/blog/64/why-you-shouldnt-use-mp3-in-your-html5-games) attached with this format, it was probably not wise to continue using this format. Because of this, I switched to `m4a` (AAC). However, after testing the program with `m4a` versus `mp3`, I have determined that using `m4a` increases the memory consumption of the program by up to a gig with increases occurring when loading new music (SSCCE not possible due to extent of the program). The file format was the only thing changed for each test.

My questions:

Is `m4a` known to be problematic in javaFX programs?

What audio formats should I be using in javaFX?

Comment: Maybe you're not up to date: http://www.audioblog.iis.fraunhofer.com/mp3-software-patents-licenses/

Comment: @fabian Ha, thanks! It appears I am not up to date.